# How do I provide databinding to an array using Aurelia and a mutiselect checkboxlist UI?

Tags: data-binding, aurelia, checkboxlist

So when the page loads, if the checkboxes were already selected previously, and the data is in the database, then the checkboxes should display as being checked in the form. Currently they are not checked (not bound to the database).

Here is the html

```
<div class="multiselect" style="width:170px; margin-top:30px">
<div class="selectBox" click.delegate="showCheckboxes('causes')">
<select>
<option style="font-weight:normal">Cause(s) to support</option>
</select>
<div class="overSelect"></div>
</div>
<iron-dropdown id="causes" horizontal-align="right" vertical-align="top" style="margin-top:25px;">
<div class="dropdown-content" style="background-color:white;box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 270px; max-height: 362px;overflow:auto;border:1px #dadada solid">
<label repeat.for="cause of causes" for="cause" style="display:block;text-align:left;margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px">
<input type="checkbox" value.bind="cause" checked.bind="selectedCause" change.delegate="causePicked()"> ${cause}
</label>
</div>
</iron-dropdown>
</div>
```

here is the JavaScript

```
  causes = ['Christian', 'Environmental', 'Hunger', 'Animal Rights', 'Homeless', 'Veterans', 'Elderly', 'other'];
  talents = ['music', 'athletics', 'childcare', 'mechanics', 'construction', 'computers', 'communication', 'chess playing', 'listening', 'other'];
  works = ['hashbrown slinging', 'nail hammering', 'leaf removal', 'floor mopping', 'counseling', 'other'];
  selectedCause = [];
  selectedTalent = [];
  selectedWork = [];

  async activate() {
    this.uid = this.app.auth.getTokenPayload().sub;
    this.user = await this.app.appState.getUser(this.uid);
    //this.app.appState.user;
    this.role = this.user.userType;
    this.causes.sort();
    this.talents.sort();
    this.works.sort();
    if (this.user.userType === 'Charity'){
      this.role = 'Charity Manager';
    }
  }
```

here is the link to repo and src code
https://github.com/WebJamApps/combined-front/blob/dev/src/dashboard-child-routes/user-account.html

https://github.com/WebJamApps/combined-front/blob/dev/src/dashboard-child-routes/user-account.js

Any suggestions are very appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it and the code examples are here for anyone else trying to figure this out

https://github.com/WebJamApps/combined-front/blob/dev/src/dashboard-child-routes/user-account.html

https://github.com/WebJamApps/combined-front/blob/dev/src/dashboard-child-routes/user-account.js